# Referencing a method from one file to another in GO language

Tags: go

I am learning Go language out of my own interest . I come from a typical OO programming .
I am bit kind of stuck in using a method present in one file from another.
So , `D:\lib\pac\abc.go`
has a method called

```
func dosomething()
{
}
```

Now , I have created one more file called def.go in the same location
In this file I am writing to function to call abc.go, but I am getting an exception called "undefined:dosomething" when I run this file using `$ go test`

```
func defFunc()
{
//call dosomething
}
```

Also both these files are in the same package. Any hint on this issue?

Answer (score 8):

Please read http://golang.org/doc/code.html and setup your GOPATH workspace correctly.

Once you've done this there should be no issue as all files in a single Go package are able to access symbols declared in any file in the package.

Answer (score 4):

Start with http://tour.golang.org/ and other documentation for starters on golang.org.

In your example I see that you have your braces on the next line, which is an error, because the compiler inserts semicolons automatically, turning your code into

```
func dosomething(); // error
{
    // code in its own scope that has nothing to do with dosomething()
}
```